# Why doesn't microtype increase tracking for non-small caps?

Tags: fonts, spacing, microtype, letterspacing

Originally, I faced the following problem: In my document, I have lots of products with each of the factors having lots of sub- and superscripts attached, so I wondered whether spacing out the factors in each product increases legibility. However, since the document is already written, I don't want to add a `\,` between each two factors (plus, I want to retain the flexiblity to change the appearance), so I thought this would be a nice job to do with `microtype` (although I don't now how to do this, precisely: increase space to normal size letters if they are not after `$` or `(` or… ).

However, I am struggling already with the very basic examples with `\SetTracking`, let alone setting tracking for my mathematical purposes.

Why does the following document only (ridiculously, but this is for demonstration) space out small caps, but nothing else?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\SetTracking{
    encoding={OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,TS1,EU1,EU2,TU},
}{1000}

\begin{document}
Upright Text.

\textsc{Text in small caps}

\textit{Text in italics}

$\alpha' i_l \lambda' k_{\lambda'} \tilde\pi = l k_l = 0$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the shown output.

Comment: @egreg Yes it does, at least on my computer. What output does produce with your installation? The desired?

Comment: Only the small caps text is subject to small tracking. Your `\SetTracking` command does nothing at all to your text, because you never use the (not existent) `sf` family.

Comment: @egreg You're right, thank you. I have corrected the code. The picture stays the same, though.

Comment: @egreg Can you provide me with an example that shows increased tracking for other font styles?